# WP7 fragment error

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

For a Windows Phone 7 app, I have created an application bar which is common for all my pages and is defined inside App.xaml

For eg. the buttons are Home, Help, About
Now, when I start my application, the default page is Home.xaml and the application bar is displayed.  When I click Help or About buttons, the navigation is performed using NavigationService and the corresponding page is displayed. But, if I click Home button, an exception is thrown - No Fragment Support at this time.

I found some suggestions where a unique querystring needs to be appended if you are trying to navigate to the same page.  Are there any other better solutions?

Also, can anyone suggest any techniques to keep such code in one place so I don't have to repeat this logic on every page for which there is an app bar icon.

Pratik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Chamberlain confirms you can't do this [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/32295ffc-0581-4022-b606-8568053f3e01).

Unique query string is the way around this. Perhaps add something as a query that is an indication of what makes the next instance of this page different.

Alternatively, you could just refresh the content in your page if that is applicable.

Comment: Thanks Mick.  One thing I can do is hide the application bar icon corresponding to that page.  Do you have any suggestions about how to do this without repeating the similar code on every page?

Comment: I did see that question as well, but I didnt feel I had enough context to give it an answer I'd be satisfied addressed all possible uses.